# VueFire this.$databaseBind(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs3, bind, vuefire

I'm trying to use returned promise from VueFire method `$databaseBind` ([here is the VueFire doc](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/realtime-data.html)), but unfortunately and I don't know why I have an error `this.$databaseBind(...).then()` is not a function.

I know that we can have this error when we try call then on non promise value, but `$databaseBind` should return a promise.
reproduction in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-borg-y41d0u?file=/src/App.vue

Here is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { VueFire, VueFireDatabaseOptionsAPI } from "vuefire";

createApp(App)
  .use(VueFire, {
    modules: [VueFireDatabaseOptionsAPI()],
  })
  .mount("#app");
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "happy-new-year",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vuefire": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
}
```

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/auth";

const config = {};
export const fb = initializeApp(config);
export const db = getDatabase(fb);
```

and usage

```
<template>
  <div>{{ testObject.$value }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "firebase/database";
import { db } from "@/plugins/firebase";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      testObject: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$databaseBind("testObject", ref(db, path)).then();
  },
};
</script>
```

Do somebody have any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: here is codesandbox with reproduction 
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-borg-y41d0u?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

There was an inner bug of VueFire. They have fixed it already.
https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/1275

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In cases like this, it would be helpful to include a link to the bug or fix in the library, so that others can follow it to learn more or confirm whether they are seeing the same issue or something else.